# Handling KeyEvent in jface SourceViewer doesn't respect doit=false

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a JFace SourceViewer that I'm modifying and I want to capture when a user presses the ENTER key inside of it, execute some code, and then cancel further execution of the ENTER event.  In other words, I don't want a carriage return in the SourceViewer text.

I have a KeyListener and a TraverseListener set up and all of them are getting fired correctly, but when I set `evt.doit = false` the carriage return still shows up in the source viewer.

If I do the same thing in a StyledText widget, it works correctly.  Is there something going on in the SourceViewer class that overrides setting doit=false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your listener is fired to late in the listener list. Remember that `StyledText` is *not* a native control and thus the handling of key, mouse, paint, resize, etc is handled by installing a listener on the canvas - see `StyledText.installListeners()`.

If this listener is run before you have the chance to set `doit = false`, then the key will already have been consumed.

You might have a better change by hooking into the `SWT.Verify` event though...